# Wait till all tasks are run in Celery python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, django-celery, celery-task

I am using **celery in python for asynchronous tasks**. I want to capture the result of it after all the tasks assigned to all workers are done.

For that, I am using the **.get() method**, but the problem with get() is that all the tasks are being assigned to a single worker which is synchronous but I want the tasks to be distributed to all the workers available.

Below is my snippet.

```
for url in urls:
    res = good_bad_urls.delay(url[1])
    res.get()
return JsonResponse(some_data)
```

Is there any other method in celery to wait until all the tasks run asynchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the problem with get() is that all the tasks are being assigned to a single worker which is synchronous

Well, not exactly. The task distribution works just the same (even if it can *seem* to do otherwise), and the tasks themselves are still async. The difference is that `result.get()` IS a blocking call - so in your case, it waits for the current task to finish until it launches the next one.

But anyway: the solution here is to [use a Group](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups). In your case, it should look something like

```
jobs = group([good_bad_urls.s(url[1]) for url in urls])
async_res = jobs.apply_async()  
result = async_res.get()
```

The `get()` call will now wait for all tasks to be finished, but they will be launched in parallel.

Comment: I did as you mentioned above but I got an error saying " res = jobs.get(),        
TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0'
Can you please help with this?

Comment: @Mahesh Sorry but  I can't help anyone with just a simple error message taken out of context . But the traceback will certainly tell you where the error is.

Comment: sure bruno, I will sort it out. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Mahesh re-reading your comment and the code snippet, there was actually something missing (my bad). I fixed the code snippet ;-)

Comment: Wonderful Bruno, Thanks!